# How to add a Canvas event from another class? WPF C#

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a MainWindow class, and that is the main window of the app. I've created another class just below the MainWindow class, and I need to add an event to a Canvas that was created in MainWindow. The method I want to add as event is also in MainWindow.

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
     public void Moving(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
     { 
        bla bla;
     }

      public Canvas Getcanvas
      {
          get
          {
             return canvas;
          }
      }
}


public class Ka
{
      public Ka()
       {
            MainWindow.Getcanvas.MouseMove += new MouseEventHandler(//HERE!!! I DONT KNOW WHAT GOES HERE, here should probably be MainWindow.Moving but I get error "An object reference.."
       }

}
```

Please help me !

Comment: `MainWindow.Getcanvas` will result an error because `getcanvas` is not static. Any way, write there the same thing (basically) that you will write on normal occasions.

Comment: If the canvas is in MainWindow, and a MainWindow method should handle a (mouse) event from the canvas, why don't you put the resepctive code inside the MainWindow class? What is the reason to have **Ka**?

Comment: `public class Ka` - EPIC. Please learn `OOP` and `C#` properly by doing `Hello, World!` type of stuff in Console Applications before trying to do complex WPF GUI stuff. After you did that, please learn MVVM before you ever write a single line of code in WPF.

Comment: Can you just tell me how to get current instance of MainWindow class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var mainWindowInstant = (MainWindow)App.Current.MainWindow;
mainWindowInstant.Getcanvas.MouseMove += new MouseEventHandler(...);
```